# Why do CSS grid items randomly start stacking on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

As you can see in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/97yo2hc3/2/, we have a grid for demonstration with some placeholder items. With a smaller number (<150ish) of items, this works fine. However, with a large number of these items, if you scroll to the end of the grid, you can see how it stops expanding and just starts stacking the divs on top of each other. Why might this be? Is this a misapplication of grid-row-end (I am using it as part of this design https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb)? Thanks for any insight!

```
/* Grid css */
.a {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.b {
  grid-row-end: span 20;
}
```

[OVERLAPPING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eulrA.png)

Comment: I cant find an issue with it as the fiddle works fine for me. what you intend with `grid-row-end: span 20`? Also why use `grid-template-columns: 305px 305px;` and make it unresponsive instead of `1fr 1fr;`?

Comment: Are you scrolled to the very bottom? The issue is also visible in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/eulrA.png. This grid was just for demo purposes but the issue still occurs with 1fr 1fr

Comment: the thing is, which such coding even for demo purpose I assume that you're a beginner and the reason I ask so sceptical. and yes, I scrolled to the very bottom.

Comment: also I forgot to say the point of grid-row-end is for this design https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb

Comment: unsure what you are looking for, your bits of code do not show a masonry like layout ??  I do not get either  the use of grid-row-end ??  also it can be done with less javascript :  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GRqwwdg

Answer (score 0):

Grid-row-end is not necessary in this case (unless you are being asked to use it?).

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row-end) you can manipulate the grid-row-end span to 20 and you'll see that it will carry out all the way to the bottom of page. Instead of this you can just adjust the height of the b div (seen below) and it will produce the same overall effect without the overlapping.

```
   .b {
  height: 350px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using grid-row-end seems like a must because I'm implementing this design https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb
Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: that still does not explain the use of grid-row-end. @Mamdlv the use of a fixed height of 350px is kinda suicide. that way you limit the cells height to 350px which will cause overflow and being super un-responsive.

Comment: ah okay no prob. What about.... grid-row-end: auto; ? This will also eliminate the overlapping but remove the gaps in between the paragraphs (if you still need them?)

Comment: That solves the overlapping but does not seem to allow for the masonry layout. How could you create the masonry layout without grid-row-end @tacoshy?

Comment: @DannyLiang by removing the grid-row-end and assuming you are going to an image into each div what you can do is add a class to that image and style it in css with 100% max-width and height that way it'll adjust proportionately to the div and it won't matter regardless of how much or little text is in the div. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/bx7wmzc4/